# jQuery Plugin not working for all elements that is applied upon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Consider the following jQuery Plugin code:

```
(function($){
$.fn.MyPluginMethod= function() {
    $(this).after('<span>Hello</span>');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

if we call this function like this:
`$('a').MyPluginMethod();` **for each** `<a>` tag that exists, it will add a `<span>` tag after it.

If we change it like this:

```
(function($){
$.fn.MyPluginMethod= function() {
    title= $(this).attr('title');
    alert(title);
};
})(jQuery);
```

It **will not** alert the title **for each** `<a>` tag that exists, only for the first occurence.

Why this behaviour?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are creating 1 instance of the plugin, so the `alert()` is called once. The reason the first example results in `span` elements after every `a` is because the `after()` jQuery function loops through the matching set of elements.

To get your latter example to work as you want, you need to loop manually:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.MyPluginMethod= function() {
        this.each(function() {
            title = $(this).attr('title');
            alert(title);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You can check to see if the plugin has been instantiated on multiple elements by using `this.length`

Comment: but in the second example, i call it with the $('a') selector, shouldn't this one loop through each of the matched elements too, and alert for each of them?

Comment: No, because as I mentioned you are creating 1 instance of the plugin.

Comment: @user2653125 no because .attr() method will return only first matched element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  this is already refering to matched set of elements, no need to wrap it again: `this.each()`

Comment: @roasted, so, the 'this' keyword, doesn't point to each specific elements, but to the list of elements?

Comment: @user2653125 ya, here 'this' refers to the jquery object (set of elements targeted by selector) on which method is apply. for example, using a method as .css(), you wouldn't need to do an each loop here. BTW, for keeping chaining, you should return the element: `return this.each()`.

Comment: one last question: what is the difference between `this` and `$(this)`, because sometimes it works with this, sometimes not, and i must use $(this)

Answer (score 0):

It will `alert` when you call it,
Also use `$.each` to call it for multiple elements like

**HTML**

```
<div title="test">test</div>
<div title="test123">test123</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
(function($){
$.fn.MyPluginMethod= function() {
    return $(this).each(function(){
      title= $(this).attr('title');
      alert(title);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
$('div').MyPluginMethod();
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SuEXP/1)

Read http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/